# Java API - Dead-end on entrySet()

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set, hashset

When examined Java's hierarchy `Set` and `Map` are different interfaces and `Map` doesn't *implement* `Collection` interface. `Set` is used to hold unique values regardless of ordering, while `Map` is used to unique keys and mapped values without ordering(except through `LinkedHashMap`, `TreeMap`). AFAIS, the major common part is that both of them make use of hash tables to store. My question is about `entrySet()` method. I just know about the method that it is used to iterate through to get key and mapped value with the key.

- Is there any other usage of the method?
- Why does its return type use **`Set`**`<Map.Entry<K,V>>`? I mean why
  **Set**, why not **ArrayList** or something?
- Does postfix of the method(set) express something why entry**Set**
  why not entry**Foo** or entry**Map** (it's already the method of `HashMap`)?

I have gotten the structures as different from each other. But it seems both take advantage of each other. It is a little bit vague to comprehend. Can you illuminate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does its return type use Set>? I mean why Set, why not ArrayList or something?

A `Set` is the preferred `Collection` type to use for a group of unique elements with no ordering. The entries of a `Map` are unique, since the keys must be unique. And the base `Map` interface assumes no ordering on its entries, so a `List` of entries wouldn't be appropriate.

> Does postfix of the method(set) express something why entrySet why not entryFoo or entryMap (it's already the method of HashMap)?

It returns a `Set` of entries, so `entrySet()` makes perfect sense.

Comment: thanks, but if we guarantee no ordering and build a structure called as X. Can we use it as return tyoe of the entrySet? I think set return type is used for reusing related same code. Am i wrong?

Comment: @snr Well, if you intend to write a class that implements the `java.util.Map` interface, your `entrySet()` method would have to return an instance of a class that implements the `java.util.Set` interface. If you are asking why the developers of Java used `Set` instead of some other interface as a return type of `entrySet`, reusing an existing interface was probably an important reason.